# Lie algebra generator relation $T^a T^b \propto T^c $ valid for any $a,b$?

Tags: lie-algebras

Given a Lie Algebra (such as $su(n), so(n))$ can I always find a set of generators + identity $\{T^a\}\cup \{id\}$ such that there exists a $c$ for any given $a,b$ such that $T^a T^b = C(a,b) T^c $ for a $a,b$-dependent function $C$ into the real/complex numbers?

Comment: What does $\propto$ stand for.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: "proportional to". So OP is asking whether there exist constants $k^{ab}_c$ such that $T^aT^b=k^{ab}_c T^c$ (with no Einstein summation, just a single constant per equation)

Comment: are $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ or $\mathfrak{so}(n)$ even closed under multiplication?

Comment: sorry, let's add $\{ id \}$ to the set of generators

Comment: Why would such identities be of interest? A representation of the Lie algebra need not preserve such product relations, only commutators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a quick ***no***. See [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/221851/the-anticommutator-of-sun-generators). Your left-hand-side is in the [universal enveloping algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra), not the Lie algebra itself.

You could have spared yourself the question, if you had considered the (presumed) preamble of your text, that surely reminded you of the spin-1, so, adjoint, representation of *su(2)*, namely 3×3 traceless Hermitian matrices, hence a trivial counterexample:
$$
S_z=\operatorname {diag} ~ (1,0,-1), \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad  S_z S_z = \operatorname {diag} (1,0,1).
$$
Now, this square cannot be written as a linear combination of $S_z$, the identity, which you allowed, and of course $S_x,S_y$ with zero in their diagonals.